# upgraded to Xcode 8 but svn status indicator missing

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode8

Just upgraded to Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a).  Updated working copy to svn 1.9.  I know there are code changes in my repository that I need to upgrade to, but I'm not seeing the "U" status indicators now in xcode.  Doing Source Control > Refresh Status does not fix the issue.  I get the "M" indicator when I change some code.  Any idea why I'm not seeing the "U" indicators next to the files that have changed?

Comment: issue still exists in Xcode 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Click on Source Control > iOS and update your svn. If you want to work with the xcode 8, you have to upgrade your SVN.